# PanoramaGL lib how change limit of zoom

Tags: android, zooming, panoramas

I use PanoramaGL  to show panorama Images, i want to change limit of zooming, anyone know can i do that in library PanoramaGL  ?

Thank's for your reponses

Answer (score 0):

In order to set maximum level of zooming, using pinch, you can use the `setMinFov` method under `panorama.getCamera()`

N.B. less is the Fov, more you can zoom